# tool to find static data in c# code

Tags: c#

I have inherited a large c# codebase. Its very messy and I suspect it might have various thread safety issues. One thing I want to do is find all static data in it. I know I could craft various regex search etc but it seems that an IL inspection tool could do a better job.

Does anybody know if such a tool exists. I have dotPeek and it doesnt, dont think reflector does it. In fact a general tool for finding all sorts of info about IL. Maybe fxcop rule could be written, i dont know enough about fxcop

EDIT: the code has > 2000 static methods so searching for 'static' is a pain. And I am worried that fancy regexes might miss something

And I also could absolutely write my own mini tool to do it. I just wondered if there is already a tool to do it

Comment: You could simply search for the `static` keyword. But thread-safety and static fields/methods are not related to each other.

Comment: It's pricey, but [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) might suit your needs. It's not clear to me what you're looking for.

Comment: It's quite easy to do using Reflection, but that's propably out of scope of your question.

Comment: Remember that a static method could still be unsafe if it relies on putting something in the application cache.

Comment: If you compile the project. Then you could recursively load all the assemblies and look through each type using Reflection to find all static fields. An automatic property will still have a backing field and two methods. This way you could create a list and then look through all of them. Resharper with Alt+Shift+T would help.

Comment: @dtb - thread safety and static data can be related. If I know that a given instance of a class or set of classes only runs on one thread (which I do know based on how I call things) then I am safe if all the data used by the code belongs to those instance(s) (I know there can be other safety issues). If there is data shared between instances then this is not the case. IN my case I have already found static writtable data

Comment: @neontapir - ndepend does the job, if you made it an answer I would flag it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pricey, but [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com) might suit your needs. I've used it before and have nothing but nice things to say about it.

It offers many kinds of code inspection and a domain-specific language (CQL) for querying code. If it's not already built-in, I'm certain you could write a simple query to find static methods.